# How can I simplify this mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these 4 queries repeated 3 times for each agent. Is there anyway to simplify/combine these queries? I don't mind using a while loop for the sums. The only thing that changes are the dates.

```
$john_week_total  = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(tp) FROM info WHERE type='life' AND date >= '$monday' AND rvp ='john smith'"),0);
$john_month_total = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(tp) FROM info WHERE type='life' AND date >= '$this_month' AND rvp ='john smith'"),0);
$john_year_total  = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(tp) FROM info WHERE type='life' AND date >= '$this_year' AND rvp ='john smith'"),0);
$john_total       = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(tp) FROM info WHERE type='life' AND rvp ='john smith'"),0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple `SUM` aggregators in the field list

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(date >= '$monday' AND rvp = 'john smith'), tp, 0) AS john_week_total
    SUM(IF(date >= '$this_month' AND rvp = 'john smith'), tp, 0) AS john_month_totalo
    -- etc.
FROM
    info
WHERE
    type = 'life'
```

---

Your code is vulnerable to injection.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli

Comment: It's not vulnerable necessarily – depends how those variables are treated above this section.

Comment: @RichBradshaw that is untrue; the queries themselves have a vulernability

Comment: The date fields are set prior to this query. Not user based. As for the mysqli, I am currently updating my entire system. It is all hard coded so it is taking some time.

Answer (score 0):

Does a query of this sort help you?

```
select
   sum(case when date >= '$monday' then tp else 0 end) as weektotal,
   sum(case when date >= '$this_month' then tp else 0 end) as monthtotal,
   sum(case when date >= '$this_year' then tp else 0 end) as yeartotal,
   sum(tp) as alltotal
from info
where type = 'life'
and rvp = 'john smith'
```